# Create SQL firewall rules with the sql server using targeted apply

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have an `azurerm_sql_server` and two `azurerm_sql_firewall_rule`s for this server.

If I do a targeted `terraform apply` to create a resource depending on the SQL server, the SQL server is created but the firewall rules are not.

Can I require the firewall rules to always be deployed with the SQL server?

"Bonus": The SQL server is in a module and the database using the server is in another module :(

#### Example code:

infrastructure/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "test" {
    count = var.enable_dbs ? 1 : 0

    location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name

    name                         = local.dbs_name
    version                      = "12.0"
    administrator_login          = var.dbs_admin_login
    administrator_login_password = var.dbs_admin_password
}

resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "allow_azure_services" {
    count = var.enable_dbs ? 1 : 0

    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name

    name                = "AllowAccessToAzureServices"
    server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.test[0].name
    start_ip_address    = "0.0.0.0"
    end_ip_address      = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

webapp/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_sql_database" "test" {
    count = var.enable_db ? 1 : 0

    location            = var.location
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    server_name         = var.dbs_name
    
    name                             = var.project_name
    requested_service_objective_name = var.db_sku_size
}
```

main.tf

```
module "infrastructure" {
    source = "./infrastructure"

    project_name = "infra"

    enable_dbs         = true
    dbs_admin_login    = "someusername"
    dbs_admin_password = "somepassword"
}

module "my_webapp" {
    source = "./webapp"

    location            = module.infrastructure.location
    resource_group_name = module.infrastructure.resource_group_name
    project_name        = local.project_name
    
    enable_db                       = true
    dbs_name                        = module.infrastructure.dbs_name
    dbs_admin_login                 = module.infrastructure.dbs_admin_login
    dbs_admin_password              = module.infrastructure.dbs_admin_password
}
```

If the whole script is applied using `terraform apply` everything is fine.

But if only module.my_webapp should be applied using `terraform apply -target module.my_webapp` the firewall rule is missing because it is not the target and the target doesn't directly require it.
The rule is necessary nonetheless and should be applied every time the database server itself is applied.

#### Possible "Solution":

Add the firewall rules as output of the `infrastructure` module:

```
output "dbs_firewall_rules" {
    value = concat(
        azurerm_sql_firewall_rule.allow_azure_services,
        azurerm_sql_firewall_rule.allow_office_ip
    )
}
```

Then add this output as input to the `webapp` module:

```
variable "dbs_firewall_rules" {
    description = "DB firewall rules required (used for the database in depends_on)"
    type        = list
}
```

And connect it in the main script:

```
module "my_webapp" {
    ...
    dbs_firewall_rules = module.infrastructure.dbs_firewall_rules
    ...
}
```

Drawback: Only one type of resources can be put in the list. This is why I renamed it from `dbs_dependencies` to `dbs_firewall_rules`.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your Terraform code in a [mcve] please? Also, are you saying that Terraform doesn't show any changes in the plan or that it applies them but nothing is actually created?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the firewall rules defined in the same tf file as the SQL Server they should be getting deployed because the server is referenced which builds up the dependency graph correctly. I have ran into issues with it not working specifically with SQL Server firewall rules.  What I eventually did was leverage the depends_on property on the SQL Server resource to make sure that those are always created. That looks like this:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "test" {
  name                = "FirewallRule1"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  server_name         = "${azurerm_sql_server.test.name}"
  start_ip_address    = "10.0.17.62"
  end_ip_address      = "10.0.17.62"
  depends_on = [azurerm_sql_server.test]
}

resource "azurerm_sql_server" "test" {
  name                         = "mysqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "mradministrator"
  administrator_login_password = "thisIsDog11"

  tags = {
    environment = "production"
  }  
}
```

Then just add each rule that you know you want to that. If you are doing your rules outside your module, then you should be able to make this an argument that you can pass into it to force the linking.

Comment: This results in an `Error: Cycle` which is only logical. Terraform is required to create the sql_server, which requires the firewall rule, which cannot be created before the server. Would have been nice, but doesn't work.

Comment: @Dehalion I had it backwards, I changed the depends on to be on the rule. Psuedo coding for the win! So sorry.

Comment: no problem, but I'm afraid this doesn't work for targeted applies either. The problem is that the rule is not in the dependency tree of the database and specifying that the firewall rule requires the database doesn't change that.

Comment: Hmm, there is a combination to make this work, I am sure.  Time to dig in.